# How would I split TO extract spaces in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, space

`Split` or `Regex.Split` is used to extract the word in a sentence(s) and store them in array. I instead would like to extract the spaces in a sentence(s) and store them in array (it is possible that this sentence contains multiple spaces). Is there easy way of doing it? I first tried to split it normally, and then use `string.split(theSplittedStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` however, that did not preserve the amount of spaces that exists.

---------- EDIT -------------

for example. If there is a sentence `"This is     a  test"`.
I would like to make an array of string `{ " ", "     ", "  "}`.

---------- EDIT END ---------

Any helps are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Extracting all the spaces would simply leave you with an array that contained as many spaces as there were in the source string. You don't need regular expressions for this, unless you wanted to track the *location* of those spaces. Please refine your question a bit.

Comment: Thanks you are correct I will edit question a bit more.

Comment: I updated my answer to include your new requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code matches all spaces in the input string and outputs their indexes:

```
const string sentence = "This  is a test   sentence.";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\s");

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Space at character {0}", match.Index);
}
```

This code retrieves all space groups as an array:

```
const string sentence = "This  is a test   sentence.";
string[] spaceGroups = Regex.Matches(sentence, @"\s+").Cast<Match>().Select(arg => arg.Value).ToArray();
```

In either case, you can look at the `Match` instances' `Index` property values to get the location of the space/space group in the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for simple one line answer.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

Based on your edited question, I believe you can do that with simple iteration like:

```
string str = "This is     a  test";

List<string> spaceList = new List<string>();
var temp = str.TakeWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace).ToList();

List<char> charList = new List<char>();
foreach (char c in str)
{

    if (c == ' ')
    {
        charList.Add(c);
    }

    if (charList.Any() && c != ' ')
    {
        spaceList.Add(new string(charList.ToArray()));
        charList = new List<char>();
    }

}
```

That would give you spaces in different elements of `List<string>`, if you need an array back then you can call `ToArray`

(Old Answer)
You don't need `string.Split`. You can count the spaces in the string and then create array like:

```
int spaceCount = str.Count(r => r == ' ');
char[] array = Enumerable.Repeat<char>(' ', spaceCount).ToArray();
```

If you want to consider [`White-Space`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9a023cx.aspx) (Space, LineBreak, Tabs) as space then you can use:

```
int whiteSpaceCount = str.Count(char.IsWhiteSpace);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, while this answer tells me how many over all spaces there are in the sentence, this does not tell me how many spaces there are individually in between each words.

Comment: @publicst119, your edit has made the question clear, Before that I thought you only needed an array of space characters.

Comment: Yes. My apology about that. The original question did seem ambiguous. with that I would like to give you the best answer but what I am looking for is slightly different.

Comment: @publicst119, I have modified my answer, I believe this can be achieved with a simple loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer as well. I would like to give both of you the answer check mark.

Comment: @publicst119, IMO, the answer with REGEX is more compact and elegant. I would rather select that as best possible answer.

Comment: Yes. I have chosen that. You have answered my question first so thought Id give you the BA for the speed but elegance is as important I agree. Thank you very much regardless!